# SoapUI opensource vs SoapUI Pro version. Is there big difference?

Tags: soapui

I am using actively SoapUI opensource version. I test there soap services and write tests there. 
If anyone has already tried it out, he should know that there is a lot of manual work needed and so it is too time consuming. For example:

- it is not possible to update the whole test suite with new endpoint (I tried to go to Service Endpoints tab and click Update all requests and test requests - somehow this feature does not work for my soapui);
- also sometimes for some test steps target source can be lost (like Request, Response, etc, when you copy and move some test suites), you have to look through manually and check whether it is filled or not;
- another thing is difficult to write xpathes just looking at the bunch of xml tags - you can simply make mistake or omit some of them (maybe in SoaupUi Pro there is some help with it, some hints)

So, I would like to know the difference between free and Pro version. I can not try myself it because I already used it long ago before I started writing tests and I do not know how such things work in Pro version.
Does Pro version helps to solve these issues or it is still same time consuming and you still need to do most of the work manually?

I would appreciate all kinds of feedback from you
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there are differences in certain functionalities between the free and paid software. However, most of the user cases are fulfilled by free software as well, and much more can be achieved by the use of groovy scripting.

Regarding your bulleted points:

1. Not sure, in which version of soapUI did you notice that issue? But it works fine.
2. Never happened to experience like that.
3. Agree with you on the xpath. But it is not difficult to learn and master on xpaths. Even with paid software uses static xpath(this only works if xml element order does not change). One needs to write xpath only if xml element order is not fixed irrespective of software edition.

Feature wise comparison between free vs paid software, please see long list [here](http://www.soapui.org/about-soapui-pro/product-comparison/soapui-and-soapui-pro.html).

Find more reasons to go for pro [here](http://www.soapui.org/about-soapui-pro/12-reasons-to-go-pro.html) like data driven, reporting etc. However, these can be done using groovy script as well and you can find them by just search on the net.

And there is active [community](http://community.smartbear.com) where lot of members get help when they got stuck with something.

The test case have to be written by user irrespective of software edition. Its a one time job that is needed. One can try out the pro edition, it is allowed for evaluation. If you want to see for yourself any time.

Its again kind of opinion base which software edition to choose, you get definitely advantage if you go paid edition. But open source edition is good enough as well.

Hope this helps, and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I use SoapUI since years and it's a really great tool.
Functional super, but sometimes difficult in handling.

SoapUI opensource vs SoapUI Pro version:

PRO: XPath assertion can be generated "point and click" on an existing response node.

PRO: If you work in a team on the same SoapUI project (on git), you really need the pro version. On the public version, a soapui project is stored within a single xml file. You'll allways get merge problems on git (we did...)
With the pro  version, EACH REQUEST is stored in a xml file. So a SoapUI PRO project contains a lot of different xml files (not only one huge file). Therefore, merging gets much more easy.

Hope this might help.

Comment: thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Your question might get closed, as such questions are considered [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here.

To determine if the -Pro version is for you, only you can do that! On the [main website](http://www.soapui.org/), along the left side, there is a very long list of topics. Most of these you have to expand by clicking on them. Some of these have the blue "PRO" icon next to them. You decide if these features are useful to you or not.

Your complaints just seem like lack of experience. For example, to update the endpoint, you can follow the documented procedure: [Centralized Endpoint](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html). The Pro version has an XPath wizard, but it is still no substitute for knowing how to correctly write your own.