# Can using free version of SOAP-UI we build a framework to maintain testcases

Tags: web-services, groovy, frameworks, soapui

I am looking for `eclipse plug-in for SoapUI`. But, `SmartBear` has stopped supporting that plug-in. I am not able to download that plug-in in my eclipse. Some source say we need to use old version of eclipse like indigo.

Moreover, `Datasource` is also not available in SoapUI free version.

Is there any way to create a framework in SoapUI free version using Groovy scripts, so that I can maintain my test cases if anything changes in future.

We are currently focusing on Rest API.

I am confused. Any suggestions/tutorials/links/ways is highly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding plug-in see this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352227/eclipse-plugin-for-soapui-for-ide-link-is-not-working)

Comment: I would recommend SOUP-UI test cases. You can use groovy scripts in there to customize those requests. Please provide some more information about what kind of tests You want to prepare. I don't see any value in complicating the job. Keep Your java tests in eclipse, and another set of tests in soup-ui =)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135104/soapui-opensource-vs-soapui-pro-version-is-there-big-difference/34137280#34137280) to see if it helps to understand better.

Comment: Shubham, As Fincio mentioned, SoapUI is enough to write organized tests into a project. Is there anything specific you are looking for apart from that? By the way, [this](https://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/groovy-datasource-teststep-dataloop-teststep-using-groovy-in-soapui/) helps to achieve `Datasource` in free version

Comment: First of all Thank you all guys for you reply and helpful comments. @Rao -> I have install the plug-in as you mentioned but  my eclipse crashed after selecting the preference as soup-ui in eclipse .. what ecilpse you are using .. I am using Mars in ubuntu linux

Comment: @Fincio  @Rao-> Now I know to write cases in Soap-UI but suppose I have 50 testcases using same API request and now my API structure is changes . Now I need to change in those all 50 cases.. I want to make a way so I can create this 1 testcase genric for all 50 cases now If something is chnage in future I just need to make change in this 1 place.

Comment: @Rao -> Yes that datasource alternative using groovy script is working like charming .. Thanks man for sharing that stuff :D

Comment: @ShubhamJain Not exactly ! Try making 3 steps in test case:
1) setRequest - basicly script manipulating request from step 2.
2) prepared request with call could add some assertions
3) loopScript
I have no idea if there is any public/open .jars to do that, You might need to write one Yourself (i did it back then), Cheers!